# add prefix to uiTextField in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, textfield

I am trying to add country code as prefix to textField so the user can enter the rest of his phone number

```
   @IBAction func phoneLogin(_ sender: Any) {
    let countryCode = "+1"
    
    guard let phoneNumber = countryCode + MobileLbl.text! else { return }
    
    if ((MobileLbl.text?.isEmpty) != nil) {
        print("Fill Your Number")
    }else {
        OTPtxt.isHidden = false
        VerifyBtn.isHidden = false
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationId, error) in
        if error == nil {
            guard let verifyId = verificationId else { return }
            self.def.setValue(verifyId, forKey: "verificationId")
            self.def.synchronize()
            
            print(verificationId)
        } else {
            print("Unable to get Secret verification from firebase", error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    }
    
}
```

I got this error **Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'**

Comment: add UILabel in front of textfield or else add leftview of your Textfiled,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're force unwrapping `MobileLbl.text!` which no longer makes it optional.  Take off the exclamation point so it's just `MobileLbl.text`.  Also have to move `countryCode` to another line as it isn't optional either.

```
let countryCode = "+1"

guard let phone = MobileLbl.text else { return nil }

let phoneNumber = countryCode + phone
```